# Not getting data in the child component from a parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from the parent component(ChallengeHeader) to the child component(DownloadButton), at first DownloadButton component gets the data and then data sets to undefined. I don't know why it's happening.
Anyone please help me with this.

ChallengeDetails

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

// custom hooks
import { useDocument } from "../../hooks/useDocument"

import ChallengeHeader from "./ChallengeHeader"
import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"

const ChallengeDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { document } = useDocument("challenges", id) // coming from firebase
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  const [figmaURL, setFigmaURL] = useState(0)

  return (
      <ChallengeHeader doc={document} />

  )
}

export default ChallengeDetails
```

ChallengeHeader component

```
import React from "react"

// Auth Context Imports
import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"

// React Router imports
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

// Reusable Components Imports
import DownloadButton from "../smallComponents/DownloadButton"
import Badge from "../smallComponents/Badge"
import Button from "../smallComponents/Button"

// Cloudinary Imports
import { Image, Placeholder, Transformation } from "cloudinary-react"
import DownloadButtonNotLogin from "../smallComponents/DownloadButtonNotLogin"

const ChallengeHeader = ({ doc, button }) => {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const displayName = user
    ? !user?.displayName
      ? user?.reloadUserInfo.screenName
      : user?.displayName.split(" ")[0]
    : "Coder"

  console.log(doc)

  const renderButton = () =>
    user ? (
      <DownloadButton color="bg-gray-900" challengeDetails={doc} />
    ) : (
      <DownloadButtonNotLogin color="bg-gray-900" />
    )

  return (
    <div className="mt-2 mb-8">
      <h2 className="font-heading text-3xl font-bold text-white">
        Hello {displayName}{" "}
        <span role="img" aria-label="Hello">
          
        </span>
        ,
      </h2>
      <p className="font-heading text-lg font-normal text-white">
        Today is a great day to start this challenge{" "}
        <span role="img" aria-label="welcome">
          
        </span>
      </p>
      <header className="mt-4 flex items-center xs:justify-center sm:justify-between bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 to-indigo-500 rounded-xl shadow-md xs:px-5 md:px-8 py-4 xs:h-full sm:max-h-96 xs:flex-wrap-reverse sm:flex-nowrap">
        <div className="xs:w-full sm:w-1/2">
          {button ? (
            <Button
              name="Explore Solutions "
              logo="fas fa-arrow-right"
              bgColor="bg-gray-900"
              handleClick={() => navigate("/solutions")}
            />
          ) : (
            renderButton()
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChallengeHeader
```

Download Button Component code

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Modal from "./Modal"
import { useCollection } from "../../hooks/useCollection"

const DownloadButton = ({ color, challengeDetails }) => {
  const [downloadingModal, setDownloadingModal] = useState(false)
  console.log(challengeDetails)

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={`${color} text-gray-300 font-semibold shadow-md py-3 px-5 rounded-xl text-base focus:outline-none block w-48`}
        // onClick={() => downloadAssets()}
      >
        <i className="animate-bounce fas fa-arrow-down mr-2"></i>Download
      </button>
      {downloadingModal && (
        <Modal
          auth
          setShowModal={setDownloadingModal}
          title="Thanks for downloading a Coding Space challenge."
          emoji=""
        />
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default DownloadButton
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like `doc` is no longer passed to `ChallengeHeader`.

Comment: but I can access the doc in ChallengeHeader, which you can see on the attached image

Comment: where does doc come from?

Comment: @AliNavidi just added a code of the parent of ChallengeHeader and doc is coming from firebase

Comment: Try adding `console.log(document);`, it looks like it's getting unset for some reason.

Comment: where I should add console.log(document);

Comment: add 
React Developer Tools
extension for your chrome it can help you a lot